# pod "Google/SignIn" vs pod "GoogleSignIn"

Tags: ios, google-signin

if you use `pod "Google/SignIn"`, it install GoogleSignIn 3.0.0

if you use `pod "GoogleSignIn"`, it install the last version 4.0.2

However if you run the app with `pod "GoogleSignIn"`, then the app crash with the message:

```
You have enabled the SignIn service in Developer Console, but it appears as though your Podfile is missing the line: 'pod "Google/SignIn" or you may need to run `pod update` in your project directory.
```

So GoogleSignIn 3.0.0 is atm the last version to use?

Comment: any response ? as pod "Google/SignIn" gives error now in GMTSessionFetcher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could make it work with:

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Google', '~> 3.0'
```

The `pod 'Google/SignIn'` is just to pass the check, since it is an older version then GoogleSignIn then it will be ignored by pod.

You'll need `pod 'Google', '~> 3.0'` also.

With this you can use Google Sign 4.0+ with no errors.

Comment: which method is recommended ? To use Google/Signin or GoogleSignIn ? All the documentation seems to point to using GoogleSignIn

Comment: You should put both to make this work, but it will use just Google/SignIn

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ,Sorry@Marckaroujo I am not able to add comment so m asking qstn on ur post.

I have added following after reading your post

```
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.0'
pod 'Google', '~> 3.0'
```

But now m getting the warning after I press pod install.

```
[!] Google has been deprecated
```

Would the warning above creates some error later in my app when it will be live to public m concerned .

Comment: It will be ok, I use it normally in a live app.

Comment: hellor @Marckaraujo I am getting some build failed error in ios while implementing google sign up in my project . Do you have any link to help me out ?